# Basic polynomial reading using linked lists

Tags: c++, printing, polynomial-math

Ok, after failing to read a polynomial, I'm trying first a basic approach to this.

So i have class polinom with function read and print:

```
#ifndef _polinom_h
#define _polinom_h

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class polinom 
{
    class term
    {
    public:
        double coef;
        int pow;

    term(){
        coef = 0;
        pow = 0;
    }  
    };

list<term> poly;
list<term>::iterator i;

public:

void read(int id) 
{ 
    term t;
    double coef = 1;
    int pow = 0;
    int nr_term = 1;

    cout << "P" << id << ":\n";
    while (coef != 0) {
        cout << "Term" << nr_term << ": ";
        cout << "coef = "; 
        cin >> coef;
        if (coef == 0) break;
        cout << " grade = ";
        cin >> pow;

        t.coef = coef;
        t.pow = pow;
        if (t.coef != 0) poly.push_back(t);
        nr_term++;
    } 
}



    void print(char var) 
    { 
        for (i=poly.begin() ; i != poly.end(); i++ ) { //going through the entire list to retrieve the terms and print them  

            if (poly.size() < 2) {
                  if (i->pow == 0) //if the last term's power is 0 we print only it's coefficient 
                     cout << i->coef;

                  else if (i->pow == 1) {
                      if (i->coef == 1)
                          cout << var;
                      else if (i->coef == -1)
                          cout << "-" << var;
                      else 
                          cout << i->coef << var;
                  }

                  else
                     cout << i->coef << var << "^" << i->pow; //otherwise we print both 
            }

            else {
                if (i == poly.end()) { // if we reached the last term  
                    if (i->pow == 0) //if the last term's power is 0 we print only it's coefficient 
                        cout << i->coef;
                    else if (i->pow == 1)
                        cout << i->coef << var;
                    else
                        cout << i->coef << var << "^" << i->pow; //otherwise we print both 
                } 

                else { 
                    if (i->coef > 0) {
                        if (i->pow == 1)//if the coef value is positive  
                            cout << i->coef << var << " + "; //we also add the '+' sign 
                        else 
                            cout << cout << i->coef << var << "^" << i->pow << " + ";
                    }

                    else {
                        if (i->pow == 1)//if the coef value is positive  
                            cout << i->coef << var << " + "; //we also add the '+' sign 
                        else 
                            cout << cout << i->coef << var << "^" << i->pow << " + ";
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

};


#endif
```

Well, it works when reading only one term but when reading more the printed coefficients are some random values and also after the last term it print '+' or '-' when it shouldn't.

So any idea what's wrong?

Thanks!

**FINAL UPDATE**

Ok, i made it work perfectly by modifying Bill's code so thanks a lot Bill and everyone else who commented or answered!

Here's the final print function:

```
   void print(char var)  
{  
 list<term>::iterator endCheckIter;  
 for (i=poly.begin() ; i != poly.end(); i++ )
{ 
     //going through the entire list to retrieve the terms and print them  
     endCheckIter = i; 
     ++endCheckIter;  

     if (i->pow == 0)
         cout << i->coef;
     else if (i->pow == 1)
         cout << i->coef << var;
     else         
         cout << i->coef << var << "^" << i->pow;

     if (endCheckIter != poly.end()) { 
         if (endCheckIter->coef > 0) 
             cout << " + "; 
         else {  
             cout << " - "; 
             endCheckIter->coef *= -1;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add some break points and run your program in a debugger.  Best way to find out what's wrong.

Comment: My advice would be to simplify things a lot. You have lots of "special case" code that's completely unnecessary. Just for a couple of examples, you don't need anything special for a one-term polynomial or for the last term in the polynomial.

Comment: Then how to access term i+1? 

I tried something like i+1->coef but it says '->' isn't a pointer.

Comment: @Jerry: The assignment probably has special cases called out. For instance, 5x^0 should read 5, -1x^2 should read -x^2, etc.

Comment: Looking a bit more, I'd also distribute the intelligence a bit more: add `read` and `write` members to `term`, so a term knows how to read or write itself. Then (for example) printing a polynomial is mostly a matter of having each term print itself.

Comment: @Bill:Yes, a few special cases make sense, but he includes a lot that don't.

Comment: Well i would do that but i don't know how to. Maybe you can show me on thizs example please?

Comment: I did so already John, don't worry!

Comment: Anyways now I'll implement the four basic operations, will I receive help for these also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (i == poly.end()) { // if we reached the last term
```

This comment shows your error.  For any given collection of items, `items.end()` returns the entry after the last item.

For instance, say I have a 5-item std::vector:

```
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4]
```

Then begin() points to:

```
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4]
/\
```

And end() points to:

```
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] []
                    /\
```

Your for loop, it looks like:

```
for (i=poly.begin() ; i != poly.end(); i++ )
```

Note that comparing `i` to `poly.end()` happens before iter is used.  As soon as `i == poly.end()`, you're done.

Your code inside of `if (i == poly.end()) {` will never be executed because this can never be true.

You can test for the end using the following:

```
// get access to the advance function
#include <iterator>

....

std::list<term>::iterator endCheckIter = i;
std::advance(endCheckIter, 1);

if (endCheckIter == poly.end())
{
  ...
}
```

But a simpler way might be:

```
std::list<term>::iterator endCheckIter = i;
++endCheckIter;
if (endCheckIter == poly.end())
{
  ...
}
```

Edit:
I'm not sure why you're getting garbage.  Add in your missing braces and handle the non-end case, and everything works here:

```
void print(char var)  
{  
    list<term>::iterator endCheckIter;  
    for (i=poly.begin() ; i != poly.end(); i++ )
    { // <- MISSING BRACE
         //going through the entire list to retrieve the terms and print them  
         endCheckIter = i; 
         ++endCheckIter;  

         cout << i->coef << var << "^" << i->pow; // <- MISSING OUTPUT
         if (endCheckIter != poly.end()) { 
             if (i->coef > 0) 
                 cout << " + "; 
             else   
                 cout << " - "; 
        }
    } // <- MISSING BRACE
}
```

Comment: so what condition would be good for the last term? 
I mean i tried poly.end() - 1 but it doesn't work!

Comment: So in my example what it would have to look like so endCheckIter will always be in front of i?

Comment: @Vlad: It works on my end.  Please post your input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: It worked for the last posted code thanks, but when I added it to my previous print function (the one with special cases) it prints ironically only the last term correctly! I'll post the final print function now so please tell me what's wrong!

Comment: @Vlad: You can't use endCheckIter for anything except the end check. `else { if (endCheckIter->coef > 0) {` <== For instance, you can't do this.

Comment: Well it doesn't show errors when I compile and run it, but when how should I do if i want x not x^1 and x^2 - x not x^2 - -x (which is wrong) and for all other special cases?

Please post print function with special cases!

Comment: Btw isn't (endCheckIter->coef > 0) present in what you posted?

Comment: I made it work like charm finally thanks to you Bill! See my final update!

Comment: @Vlad: Yes, it looks like I made that typo.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, now that Vlad has decided how he's *going* to do it, here's how I'd do it:

```
#ifndef _polinom_h
#define _polinom_h

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

#include "infix_iterator.h"

using namespace std;

char var;

class polinom {
    class term {
        double coef;
        int power;
        ostream &write(ostream &os) const { 
            // At least to me, the logic is easier to follow if we 
            // handle one piece at a time. 
            // It may be longer, but I think it's easier to understand.

            // First, if the coefficient is negative, subtract the term instead of adding it.
            if (coef < 0) 
                // backspace over the "+ " and print '- ' in its place.
                os << "\b\b- ";

            // Then print the absolute value of the coefficient (if needed).
            if (fabs(coef) != 1)
                os << fabs(coef);

            // Then print the var (if needed)
            if (power != 0)
                os << var;

            // then print the power (if needed)
            if (abs(power) > 1)
                os << "^" << power;

            // And we're done.
            return os;
        }

        // support inserting a term into a stream.
        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, term const &t) {  
            return t.write(os); 
        }

    public:
        term(double c=0.0, int p=0) : coef(c), power(p) {}
        bool read(std::ostream &os, std::istream &is, int num) {
            // This is only slightly modified from the originally posted question
            os << "\nTerm " << num << ": coef = ";
            is >> coef;
            if (coef == 0.0)
                return false;
            if (coef != 0.0) {
                os << " grade = ";
                is >> power;
            }
            return true;
        }

        bool operator<(term const &other) const { 
            // order by descending powers.
            return other.power < power;
        }
    };

    list<term> poly;

public:
    void read(int id) {
        term t;
        int nr_term = 1;
        std::cout << "P: " << id;

        // Read and save individual terms:
        while (t.read(std::cout, std::cin, nr_term++))
            poly.push_back(t);
    }

    void write(char var) { 
        // sort the polynomial so the highest powers come first.
        poly.sort();

        // save the variable name for later use.
        ::var = var;

        // Print out all the terms:
        std::copy(poly.begin(), poly.end(), infix_ostream_iterator<term>(std::cout, " + "));
    }
};

#endif
```

Using this is pretty trivial:

```
#include "polynom.h"

int main() { 
    polinom p;

    p.read(1);

    p.write('x');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Vlad: Oops. Sorry 'bout that. See: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/msg/a746a588cedfa44b. It's basically like an ostream_iterator except that it only prints delimiters between items instead of after every one.

Answer (score 0):

```
void print(char var)
{
    for (list<term>::const_iterator i = poly.begin(), e = poly.end(); i != e; ++i) {
        if (i != poly.begin() || i->coef < 0) {
            cout << (i->coef > 0 ? '+' : '-');
        }
        if (abs(i->coef) != 1) {
            cout << abs(i->coef);
        }
        if (i->pow == 0) {
            if (abs(i->coef) == 1) {
                cout << 1;
            }
        } else {
            cout << var;
            if (i->pow != 1) {
                cout << '^' << i->pow;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's the almost the same with what Bill, but how it will look if i want x for x^1 and for example other than 6x^4 - -3x^2 it should be 6x^4 - 3x^2, but anyway thanks!

Comment: i checked them, it works pretty well but i want without x^1 or 5x^2--x for example. What to do?

Comment: double '-' is impossible... may be you have tried with incomplete version of the code?... x^1 is impossible too.

Comment: Well it doesn't work because abs can't work double, but anyways it doesn't matter I made it to work like i wanted by modifying Bill's code and it works beautifully, thanks alot Bill and you Corwin as well!

Comment: c++ standard abs() function can ;) probably you did include c header file.

Comment: It doesn't matter now, but thanks and please answer to my future question too please. ;)

Comment: I can't rep you because the post is too old!